# Pandas dataframe yielding float and no float at the same time

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am aiming at transfering som dataframe columns to a dictionary, but I have lots of NaNs in the data, and I'm trying to remove them iterating since I am not being lucky with df.fillna.  The thing is, I need to convert all strings to float first, and I am using the fd.iloc method for that, but it seems I am creating a Schrödinger data type at the same time?  In the picture belowcan be seen how :

```
            if type(eu_stocks.iloc[j, i]) != 'float':
                print('hov!')
                print(eu_stocks.iloc[j, i])
                print(type(eu_stocks.iloc[j, i]))
```

Is both yielding float and no float at the same time. What am I doing wrong with the use of iloc?
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pandas uses types differently. If `f_col` is a column of floats, `type(f_col)` is `pandas.core.series.Series`.

Try changing

```
if type(eu_stocks.iloc[j, i]) != 'float':
```

to this

```
if eu_stocks.iloc[j, i].dtypes != 'float':
```